# C++ Why These Same Codes (i think) Giving Different Outputs?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

I'm watching tutorial series for c++ from youtube channel Trevor Payne. https://youtu.be/iMbvbWlrMj8?list=PL82YdDfxhWsCyZLsg_kXhH8sy5ixQNras&t=657 In here his console starts counting from 1 to 10, While my code starts from 0. Why?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    for (;;) {
        cout << i++ << endl;
        if (i > 10)
            break;
    }

    string y; 
    getline(cin, y);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Thanks for the link. I have read through the page but still can't see what i'm doing different. Both video and my code looks the same.

Comment: His window is not very tall, it is possible the 0 scrolled off.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common mistake for those new to programming in general. It has to do with prefix and postfix increment.

Basically, when you postfix increment a variable (i.e use the increment operator *after* the variable name), the variable is incremented **but** the returned value in the current statement is not the incremented but the "old" value.

When you prefix increment a variable (i.e use the increment operator *before* the variable name), the variable is incremented **and** the incremented value is returned in the current statement.

Try it yourself:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i=0;
    int y=i; // both 0

    cout << "i is: " << i++ << endl; // postfix increment
    cout << "but y is: " << ++y << endl; // prefix increment

    cout << "now i is: " << i << endl;
    cout << "and y is: " << y << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know the difference between postfix/prefix increments but both i and Trevor (Guy in the video) are using postfix. When using that, it should start from 0 right? But his console starts from 1 as if he is using prefix but still ends at 10 (shouldn't it end at 11 if he was using prefix?)

Comment: @Çnra, I've checked the video and it doesn't make sense to me what happens on his computer... It is funny that before he fixes his infinite loop the output was as expected.

Comment: @Çnra Looking closer at the video I think its simply a case of overflow. If he had a larger window, you would see the 0 at the top.

Comment: @pastaleg indeed!!

Comment: @pastaleg I spent last 2.5 hours searching for what im doing wrong :D Its good to hear nothing was wrong. I will delete my post in few minutes to prevent further confusion.